# Is there a summary of all rules for each type of logic?

Tags: reference-request, logic

I am learning about rules in logic and type systems and am having to piece together fragments of them from different articles and books, which makes it difficult to see the subtle differences in each system.

Is there a good or standard reference/cheatsheet that summarizes the rules for each system, sort of like below? That would make it much easier to compare and contrast.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwaLM.png]

If there isn't a purely cheat-sheet summary of rules for each system, what is the best book or resource that contains the most complete collection?

Ideally looking for a book that organizes *all* logics, mainly all the main classical (propositional, first-order, higher order, ...) and non-classical logics (intuitionistic, linear, modal, temporal, relevance, hoare, ...).

If there isn't anything that does this, what are some of the next best resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Encyclopedia of Proof Systems](http://proofsystem.github.io/Encyclopedia/), an ongoing project which has the aim to provide such a compendium of proof systems. It is still work in progress, so not really complete - but then, given the huge number of logics around, that's hardly possible anyways. By the way, everyone is encouraged to contribute!

Another resource for Hilbert-style formulations would be [John Halleck's website](http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/structures/systems/index.html).

Comment: PERFECT! This is exactly what I was looking for :D